# SQL Server 2008 Replace substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a `Screen` table which has `name` and `display_name` columns. I am trying to replace the word `Lawfirm` with `Law Firm` in `name` and `display_name` columns for all the records of `Screen` table.

My SQL experience is pretty premature, I am wondering is there a way to achieve this using a SQL script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
update screen
    set display_name = replace(display_name, 'Lawfirm', 'Law Firm')
    where display_name like '%Lawfirm%';
```